# Why Google test executes automatically unselected test cases?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, googletest

I have created a GUI to select test cases. The test cases are made in `Google Test Framwework`. The problem here is if I am selecting a test case, there is another test case which is looking nearly similar is getting selected and getting executed automatically, like below,

```
TEST_F(ClassName, Test1){}
TEST_F(ClassName, Test2){}
```

If I am selecting ClassName then it running only test cases which are belong to `ClassName` class.
The problem happening if I have a Class name like,

```
class ClassNameXYZ{};
TEST_F(ClassNameXYZ, TestA){}
TEST_F(ClassNameXYZ, TestB){}
```

So, in the GUI I am getting `tree like`.

```
  ClassName
       |_Test1
       |_Test2
  ClassNameXYZ
       |_TestA
       |_TestB
.....
.....
```

If I selecting `ClassName` then it runs `ClassNameXYZ` too.
But when I am selecting `ClassNameXYZ` it does not run `ClassName`.

So I would like to know `ClassNameXYZ` getting executed because the `substring` ClassName is present in it?
If is it so, then how to get rid of this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/AdvancedGuide#Running_a_Subset_of_the_Tests)... 
But I am very very unhappy that, google test is running like this.

`• ./foo_test --gtest_filter=*Null*:*Constructor* Runs any test whose full name contains either "Null" or "Constructor".`

Google people should look into this problem. Because there may be a case that `4-5` test cases may of nearly same name then it will a big problem if at all you are going for a filter.

Like.

```
TestCase
 |_Test1
 |_Test11
 |_Test122
 |_Test1345
 |_Test1346
```

If a person filters `TestCase.Test1` then all the test cases will run because all the test cases use `TestCase.Test1XXXX`.

Comment: Don't use the trailing `*` then.  Doing `--gtest_filter=TestCase.Test1` should run only Test1 and no others.

Comment: @Fraser: I did try the same. But gtest didnot run the test case.
`::testing::GTEST_FLAG(filter) = "Test1";` (excluding`*`).